# Pull first instance of value from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The title isn't great, so I'll try to describe what I'm looking for.
If you'd like to see some code first, this works but takes way too long (my df "Test" is 22e6 rows in length).

This df is "Test":

```
    SA      DATE        MTRCYCCD
0   123     2015-07-31  H
1   123     2015-12-27  H
2   123     2015-06-09  H
3   123     2015-07-01  H
4   123     2015-12-28  H
```

This df is "meterread":

```
    Serial  KWH_DEC_2014    KWH_JAN_2015 
0   B       11/24/2014      12/24/2014
1   C       11/25/2014      12/26/2014
2   D       11/26/2014      12/29/2014
3   F       12/1/2014       12/30/2014
4   H       12/2/2014       12/31/2014
```

This df is "Item16":

```
    SA_ID   MTRCYCCD    DA_DEC_2014  DA_JAN_2015
0   123     H           BUNDLED      NaN
1   123     H           BUNDLED      NaN         
2   123     H           BUNDLED      NaN
3   123     H           BUNDLED      NaN
```

I would like the output file to be a new column in "Test":

```
    SA      DATE        MTRCYCCD  LSE
0   123     2015-07-31  H         BUNDLED
1   123     2015-12-27  H         BUNDLED
2   123     2015-06-09  H         BUNDLED
3   123     2015-07-01  H         BUNDLED
4   123     2015-12-28  H         BUNDLED
```

This is my current code (which works, but is very very slow):

```
Test['LSE'] = ''
for i in range(len(Test)): 
    t = (meterread[meterread['Serial'] == Test.iloc[i,2]] > Test.iloc[i,1]).iloc[:,1:]
    Item16col = t.columns[t.values.argmax()]
    row = (Item16.index[Item16.iloc[:,0] == Test.iloc[i,0]])
    col = Item16.columns.get_loc('DA_'+Item16col.lstrip('KWH_'))
    Test.iloc[i,3] = Item16.iloc[row,col].values
    print(Test.iloc[i,3],Item16.iloc[row,col].values)
```

I know I'm committing some faux-pas here, specifically looping through rows in a dataframe.  This is what I need help with -- how can I vectorize, or otherwise improve the speed of this code?

The code does the following:
1. Find the column index in 'meterread' which corresponds to the first instance of the date in 'Test' falling between the dates (for that MTRCYCCD) of 'meterread'.
2. Pull the column name, strip KWH_ and replace with DA_.  Assign this to 'col'
3. Find the row in 'Item16' which matches SA_ID with SA in 'Test'.
4. Use these row and col to pull from 'Item16' the DA status for that specific month.  Either BUNDLED, NaN, or other.
5. Assign the DA status to a new column in 'Test', labeled LSE.

As I said, the code works, but it takes a very long time (22e6 rows!  and really, times three).

Comment: Also, I get that the numbers/dates posted don't quite work.  Consider this hand waving.

Comment: Why bother with "Pull the column name, strip KWH_ and replace with DA_" (`Item16col = t.columns[t.values.argmax()]`)? Won't the result always be `KWH_DEC_2014`?

Comment: In fact, what's the purpose of involving the `meterread` DataFrame at all? The date lookup doesn't seem to have any bearing on the expected output.